# How to check if user is logged in and has a active session in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

Is it possible to check if a user is logged in and has a active session in ASP.NET using only the username? I need some sort of service to return true/false based on username as input. I don't have access to Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Comment: If your application uses a SQL database, you can run exec sp_who2 in SQL Server Management Studio to show all active sessions connected to the said SQL database. As to your question, I haven't looked if that can be done programmatically. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible. Once the user has logged on set a session variable
I like to make a class for Users then turn it into a session variable:

eg:

```
   userData loggedIn = new userData(username, email);
   Session["User"] = loggedIn
```

Then when I'm checking if somebody is logged in I use something in the page load like

```
    if (Session["User"] != null);
```